# Video corrupted because of force restart when capturing

Tags: video-recording, capturing, avi, mixer

[image: Video corrupted]

I was capturing my video using **Vmix Live Video Streaming & Video Mixer Software** when suddenly my computer restart itself. The file was saved with size of 3GB in my local drive. I used AVI format.

But when I try to open the video file, it looks like the file is corrupted and couldn't be opened. What can I do to fix this??

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:**
This is the screenshot when I open the file in VirtualDub Hex editor
[image: Using Hex Editor]

**UPDATE:**
This is the screenshot again where the zeros end.
[image: Zeros end]

**UPDATE:**
This is the screenshot of a working file.
[image: Screenshot of a working file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't panic
2. Download virtualdub and try to open in it. Try select "direct stream copy" and save new file. AVI container very easy to fix.
3. If you using h264 codec inside, you can try to use my tool https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer

Comment: It doesn't work, it says **"the file is of an unknown or unsupported file type"** when I tried to open it.

Comment: VirtualDub -> tools -> hex editor -> open file -> post screenshot here

Comment: Ok, I've posted it in my question. I can't screenshot all of them though, I think it have million lines of hexadecimals.

Comment: Ok, things goes worse than expected. Try to scroll down, you see anything other, than zeros?

Comment: Yes, the zeros stop at line 1F6E0

Comment: Very good. You posted piece of uncompressed sound. Now, can you record few seconds /using Vmix Live Video Streaming & Video Mixer Software/ and save it in proper way? May be you have some old files? I need only small piece of working file with exactly same parameters.

Comment: Where a you? You don't need help anymore?

Comment: I'm very sorry for my very slow response, it has been a very busy week. However I still really need your help and very glad to have it, I've added new screenshot of a working file. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Copy your damaged file (all experiments done only on copy!) and paste header of healtly file in it (0...0x150, before zeros starts). Try to open in VirtualDub.

Comment: Also, you can try this: https://expirebox.com/download/4338e9acafa820fc55a521c280afca21.html (pass: 123), just drop broken file over avi.exe and wait some time. This is bad method, as it uses reencoding in process. But you will see content of your file, what can be restored.

Comment: How to copy and paste the header?? In hex editor I can only view them but not edit them.

Comment: Try winhex. Or app on my link.

Comment: I've replaced the header but it didn't work, but now in virtualdub it says **"The main movi block is missing"**

Comment: Okay, but copy a little more. Find on good file a small string "movi", skip 16 bytes and copy all header, including "movi" and 16 bytes to copy of the broken file.  Also, you tried tool on my link, may be it will be easier?

Comment: How your progress?

Comment: I've copied the movi block, and opened it in Virtual Dub, now I can play it :)
.
Although there's some warning:
_[!] AVI: Index not found or damaged -- reconstructing via file scan.

[!] AVI: Invalid chunk detected at 96740. Enabling aggressive recovery mode.

[!] AVI: Keyframe flag reconstruction was not specified in open options and 
    the video stream is not a known keyframe-only type.  Seeking in the video 
    stream may be extremely slow._

But still, the video can be played now, I will click save as AVI now. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: It's very good. Thanks!! Of course, you could just use a ready tool, which I uploaded for you.

Comment: Yes, i want to try that but when i want to download the app, the link has been expired. I would be glad if you could re-upload it, thanks.

Comment: Actually, you don't need it anymore, as you can open your file

Comment: You can also use an ffmpeg copy command. Usually fixes this kind of thing, and no quality loss.